# ng-class multiple conditions

Tags: angularjs, conditional-statements, ng-class

I would like to apply multiple conditions into ng-class so the upper limit on 'u.Credit' will be let say 10000. Here is my code:

```
<tr ng-repeat="u in user.tables.tbl1" ng-init="u.DateAdded = JSONtoDATE(u.DateAdded)" ng-class='{lastRow : $last}' ng-model="myIndex = $index">
  <td>{{u.ID}}</td>
  <td>{{u.Name}}</td>
  <td>{{u.Email}}</td>
  <td>{{u.DateAdded}}</td>
  <td ng-class='{selectedRow : u.Credit >= creditValue}'>{{u.Credit}}</td>
</tr>
```

... I have tried something like this but it didn't work:

```
<td ng-class='{selectedRow : ((u.Credit >= creditValue) && (u.Credit < 10000))}'>{{u.Credit}}</td>
```

Comment: Could the problem be related to your use of `&&` as opposed to `&amp;&amp;`? The ng-class is still parsed as any html or xml attribute string, as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace that with a function call on your controller:

```
<td ng-class='getClassForCurrentRow(u)'>{{u.Credit}}</td>
```

I'm not sure what `creditValue` is and from where is populated, if it's from the controller then you don't need a new parameter, if not then add it to the function `getClassForCurrentRow(u, creditValue)`.

And in your controller define the class:

```
{...}
$scope.getClassForCurrentRow = function(record) {
   if (record.Credit >= $scope.creditValue) {
      return "selectedRow";
   }
   return "";
}
```

Be careful to leave this function as simple as possible, because Angular runs it on every cycle to determine if something changed.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="" ng-click="addFavorite(myfav.id);favorite=!favorite">
 <i class="fa orange" ng-class="{'fa-star': favorite || fav==myfav.id, 'fa-star-o': !favorite}"></i>
```

Answer (score 0):

My apologize guys, I have made little mistake in tested code (I'm JS beginner) which had negative impact on desired functionality and after correcting it I have to say that expression I have claimed as 'not-working' is actually working:

```
selectedRow : (u.Credit >= creditValue && u.Credit < 10000)
```

However, your answers are very valuable to me as I'm learner. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For multiple conditions in ng-class its better to create a function in controller that returns true or false for selectedRows in ng-class. like below:

```
{...}
$scope.getSelectedRow = function(record, creditValue) {
   if ( record.Credit >= creditValue && record.Credit < 10000) {
      return true;
   }
   return false;
}
```

Call this like:

```
<td ng-class='getSelectedRow(u,creditValue)'>{{u.Credit}}</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like below..

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<style>
.selectedRow{
color:#987789;
font-size:30px;
}
.unSelectedRow{
color:#234567;
font-size:30px;
}
</style>
<body ng-app="" ng-init="Credit = 10;creditValue=9;">
<p ng-class="{true: 'selectedRow', false: 'inactive'}[Credit >= creditValue]">Value : {{Credit}}</p>
<p ng-class="{false: 'unSelectedRow'}[Credit < creditValue]">Value : {{Credit}}</p>

</body>
```